# How to defin time out on python 3 process?

Tags: python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, timeout

I'm trying to use process in order to define a time for a function.
I sucessfully created a simple process and run it:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
stemp = list()

#simple function for testing purpose
def f(name):
    print('hello, ', name)
    stemp.append(name)

#define a process and run it
p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.run()
```

But when I try to use p.join to define a timeout (see code bellow). I get the error message "AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute '_target'"

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We create a Process
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))

    # We start the process and we block for 5 seconds.
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout=5)
    p.run()

    # We terminate the process.
    p.terminate()
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove `p.run()`.

Comment: Thanks @MehdiSadeghi removing p.run let the the code run. But it doesn't perform the stemp.append(name) & print('hello, ', name) from the f function. Is there an easy way to transfer result of the process to the main environment?